# Not able to register Plugin in Zend Framework application.ini

Tags: zend-framework

my plugins directory sits in

```
application
  /plugins
    Dbcount.php
    ModuleLayout.php
```

i am unable to register the plugin with frontController. here is my application.ini code.

```
#Plugin path and namespace
pluginPaths.Plugins = APPLICATION_PATH "/plugins"
autoloaderNamespaces[] = "Plugin_"

#register plugin
resources.frontController.plugins[] = "Plugin_DbCount"
```

it gives me following error.

```
Warning: include_once(Plugin/DbCount.php) [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Users/azhararmar/htdocs/joofris/v1/library/Zend/Loader.php on line 146

Warning: include_once() [function.include]: Failed opening 'Plugin/DbCount.php' for inclusion (include_path='/Users/azhararmar/htdocs/joofris/v1/application/../library:/Users/azhararmar/htdocs/joofris/v1/library:.:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.2/lib/php') in /Users/azhararmar/htdocs/joofris/v1/library/Zend/Loader.php on line 146

Fatal error: Class 'Plugin_DbCount' not found in /Users/azhararmar/htdocs/joofris/v1/library/Zend/Application/Resource/Frontcontroller.php on line 117
```

what is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the default appnamespace `Application`, then the plugin stored in `application/plugins/DbCount.php` should be named `Application_Plugin_DbCount`. Use the full classname when you register:

`resources.frontController.plugins[] = "Application_Plugin_DbCount"`

Comment: i am using the custom Namespace `Plugin_` appreciate your solution. but why is it not working with my code

Comment: BEcause autoloader namespaces look up in `/library` not under `/application`

Answer (score 1):

To use the namespace like that your `Plugin` classes need to be under Library or you need to map them else where. Looks like you have the frontcontroller plugin set up right but incorrect autoload definitions.

Easiest thing to do here is to name your plugins `YourAppNamespace_Plugin_YourPluginName`.

Answer (score 1):

They are two types of plugin in ZF . You are mixing some part of each .

To make your code work do

```
1) put application dir in include_path
2) change directory name plugins to 'Plugin'
```